# Aligning matrices with enumerate

Tags: lists, matrices

I am trying to align matrices in three questions like an array but I have an enumerate list. If I create the array then the lists won't show.

```
\item \(\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            20 & 25 & 20 \\
            15 & 20 & 18 \\
            18 & 23 & 22
            \end{pmatrix*}\)
            \(\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            x \\
            y \\
            z
            \end{pmatrix*}\) =
            \(\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            975 \\
            810 \\
            965
            \end{pmatrix*}\) 
            \(\qquad\qquad\Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            x \\
            y \\
            z
            \end{pmatrix*}\) = 
           \(\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            10 \\
            15 \\
            20
            \end{pmatrix*}\)
    \item \(\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            90 & 95 & 80 \\
            80 & 85 & 90 \\
            75 & 90 & 95
            \end{pmatrix*}\)
           \(\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            x \\
            y \\
            z
            \end{pmatrix*}\) = 
           \(\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            86 \\
            86 \\
            88
            \end{pmatrix*}\)
            \(\qquad\qquad\Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            x \\
            y \\
            z
            \end{pmatrix*}\) = 
           \(\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            0.3 \\
            0.2 \\
            0.5
            \end{pmatrix*}\)
    \item \(\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            5,000 & 4,000 \\
            6,000 & 5,000
            \end{pmatrix*}\)
           \(\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            x \\
            y \\
            \end{pmatrix*}\) = 
           \(\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            37,000,000 \\
            45,000,000 \\
            \end{pmatrix*}\)
            \(\qquad\qquad\Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            x \\
            y \\
            \end{pmatrix*}\) = 
           \(\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            5000 \\
            3000
            \end{pmatrix*}\)
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please provide a full compilable example that others can copy and test without having to add anything. Here for example, one needs to know that `mathtools` is needed

Comment: You'll probably have to make a box on each manually to align the `\Rightarrow`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an automatic solution, based on the `eqparbox` package. I defined an `\eqmathbox` command, which accepts $2$ optional arguments (the end of name of the box, and the alignment: `l, r` or `c`) and one mandatory argument: the contents of the math box.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse} 
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\NewDocumentCommand\Eqmathbox{O{0}O{l}m}{\eqmakebox[Form#1][#2]{\ensuremath{ \displaystyle#3}}}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\sisetup{group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits = 4}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \(\Eqmathbox{\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        20 & 25 & 20 \\
        15 & 20 & 18 \\
        18 & 23 & 22
        \end{pmatrix*}
        \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        x \\
        y \\
        z
        \end{pmatrix*} =
        \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        975 \\
        810 \\
        965
        \end{pmatrix*}}
        \Rightarrow\Eqmathbox[1][r]{\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        x \\
        y \\
        z
        \end{pmatrix*} =}
       \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        10 \\
        15 \\
        20
        \end{pmatrix*}\)
\item \(\Eqmathbox{\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        90 & 95 & 80 \\
        80 & 85 & 90 \\
        75 & 90 & 95
        \end{pmatrix*}
       \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        x \\
        y \\
        z
        \end{pmatrix*} =
        \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        86 \\
        86 \\
        88
        \end{pmatrix*}}
        \Rightarrow\Eqmathbox[1][r]{\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        x \\
        y \\
        z
        \end{pmatrix*} =}
       \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        0.3 \\
        0.2 \\
        0.5
        \end{pmatrix*}\)
\item \(\Eqmathbox{\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        \num{5000} & \num{400}0 \\
        \num{6000} & \num{5000}
        \end{pmatrix*}
        \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        x \\
        y \\
        \end{pmatrix*} =
       \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        \num{37000000} \\
        \num{45000000 }\\
        \end{pmatrix*}}
        \Rightarrow\Eqmathbox[1][r]{\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        x \\
        y \\
        \end{pmatrix*} =}
       \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        \num{5000} \\
        \num{3000}
        \end{pmatrix*}\)
        \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way. Note that you are adding a lot of unneeded `\(...\)`-pairs. I've removed them. The only reason `memoir` is used, is because it is the default in my editor.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \(
  \mathmakebox[6cm][l]{
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            20 & 25 & 20 \\
            15 & 20 & 18 \\
            18 & 23 & 22
            \end{pmatrix*}
            \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            x \\
            y \\
            z
            \end{pmatrix*} =
            \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            975 \\
            810 \\
            965
            \end{pmatrix*}
          }
          \qquad\qquad
          \Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            x \\
            y \\
            z
            \end{pmatrix*} = 
            \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            10 \\
            15 \\
            20
            \end{pmatrix*}\)
    \item \(
      \mathmakebox[6cm][l]{
      \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            90 & 95 & 80 \\
            80 & 85 & 90 \\
            75 & 90 & 95
            \end{pmatrix*}
            \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            x \\
            y \\
            z
            \end{pmatrix*} = 
            \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            86 \\
            86 \\
            88
            \end{pmatrix*}
            }
            \qquad\qquad\Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            x \\
            y \\
            z
            \end{pmatrix*} = 
            \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            0.3 \\
            0.2 \\
            0.5
            \end{pmatrix*}\)
    \item \(
      \mathmakebox[6cm][l]{
      \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            5,000 & 4,000 \\
            6,000 & 5,000
            \end{pmatrix*}
            \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            x \\
            y \\
            \end{pmatrix*} = 
            \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            37,000,000 \\
            45,000,000 \\
            \end{pmatrix*}
            }
            \qquad\qquad\Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            x \\
            y \\
            \end{pmatrix*} = 
            \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
            5000 \\
            3000
            \end{pmatrix*}\)
          \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]